# Form action address trouble

Tags: php, forms, action

I'm having trouble with my search form action, I would like to get:

```
index.php?act=page1&filter=bell
```

but I'm getting:

```
index.php?filter=bell
```

It is missing bolded part:

```
index.php? <strong>act=page&</strong> filter=bell
```

Is this possible to get and how?

Comment: How would you like to get the full URL?

Comment: Can you add your form action or what create that url?

Comment: What do I need to type in <form action="???" method="get"> to get in my address bar this: index.php?act=page1&filter=bell, because if I type in action ?act=page1 it does not work I'm getting in address bar index.php?filter=bell

Comment: My form: <form action="?act=page1" method="get"><input name="filter" type="text" placeholder="Filter" value="<?php echo $pojam; ?>" autofocus class="filter"></form>

Comment: you never posted your form in the original question. Had you done that, you would have received a better response and most likely a solution. You posted "after" in comments, which should have been part of your original post.

Comment: hey @Fred -ii- I'm new in this, this is my first question and everyone makes mistake first time. Next time will be better, I learned from this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, solved the problem! I added new hidden element and my problem is solved.

```
<form action="" method="get">
   <input type="hidden" name="act" value="page1">
   <input name="filter" type="text" placeholder="Filter" value="<?php echo $pojam; ?>" autofocus class="filter">
</form>
```

And now I'm getting the address index.php?act=page1&filter=bell

Thanks for the help. :)